# Eclipse - Ignore Entire Directories

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I use Aptana Studio (based on Eclipse).  I'm trying to get Eclipse to completely ignore an entire directory inside a project.  I mean COMPLETELY.  I don't want it to display in the project folder.  I don't want Eclipse to even be aware it exists.

Unfortunately, all my efforts to add it as a filter don't work. See http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=8340#p33714 . I think the filter only prevents the folder from being displayed in the project display.   It doesn't keep Eclipse from actually looking at all the files in that folder for code assist, etc.

My problem is that directory has thousands of text files.  So, each time Eclipse opens or refreshes this project, it analyzes all those files.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a linked resource (pointing off to some other file/folder on disk) with the same name in the same location in the resource tree, then the real folder on disk will be hidden from the resource model.

Unfortunately you can't create the linked resource if the real directory is already there in the project structure.  You can try something like this:

1. On disk, rename/move the directory in question
2. Refresh the project, the directory is gone
3. Create a linked resource ( New -> File/Folder >> Advanced -> Link to file in the file system ).  Name it the same as the original directory.
4. On disk, restore the original name of the directory
5. Refresh project.

Comment: Ummm.... thanks.  Not sure I understand any of that, but I appreciate you responding.  

I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 35):

Not sure about this aptana thing, but there is a convenient way to do it in native eclipse:

1. Right-click a project folder in Project Explorer tree and go to "Properties".
2. Resource -> Resource Filters.
3. Add as much exclusion filters for files/folders as you like.

If your project tree is not refreshed immediately, press F5 to enforce it.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. It did exactly what the original question described.

Comment: what version of eclipse is this included in? Not seeing it in 3.5.x

Answer (score 13):

Consider also the 'Derived' checkbox:  right-click an entry in the package explorer, choose properties, check Derived.  This may solve part of your problem.

See http://robmayhew.com/eclipse-ignore-folder/

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking "Properties" and unchecking all permissions.