# How do I stop Eclipse from refreshing some dir?

Tags: eclipse, refresh

Every time I start Eclipse it tries to refresh an entire project, which translates to more than 10 minutes of wait time, not to mention the ridiculous amount of memory it would consume.

I know there's a global setting to turn off automatic refreshing (`General -> Workspace -> Refresh automatically`). Is there a way to turn that off on individual directories? The rationale is that some directories are seldom changed in some of my projects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg24692.html), <del>no</del>:

- no settings per projects (for disabling auto-refresh)
- no settings per directory within one project.

---

For more recent versions of Eclipse, as detailed in [Eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fresourcefilters.htm), you can use **Resource filters** (also initially [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11140250/6309) by [`pcoucke`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194584/pcoucke))

> Resource filters can be created, edited and removed in the `File > Properties > Resource > Resources Filters` property page for a project or folder resource.
>
> Resource filters only apply to files and/or folders that are implicitly included in the workspace by the refresh operation
> An "Exclude" resource filter prevent all files and/or folders that match the filter condition to be included in the workspace during the refresh operation.

I mentioned an example in "[How to have `.git` folders ignored by Eclipse projects](https://superuser.com/a/225364/141)"

[image: resource filter]

Comment: This sucks. I don't want to close a project just to disable refreshing on some of its directories. Well, hope some future Eclipse will have a fine-grained control over how "refreshing" works.

Comment: @Fortepianissimo: true... may be a suggestion to add to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Answer (score 11):

For individual directories you can do it by adding Resource filters.

1. Right-click a project folder in Project Explorer tree and go to "Properties".
2. Resource -> Resource Filters.
3. Add as much exclusion filters for files/folders as you like.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6321688/1194584

Comment: Great, this is the solution, no hack like the other answers. Wondering why I am the first person to vote this up.

Comment: Can confirm this is working. The accepted answer is old and irrelevant

Comment: Great, this saved me

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is the refresh on startup, try: Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Refresh workspace on startup.

Answer (score 2):

I found an effective hack that can in effect make Eclipse ignore a directory. See [Eclipse - Ignore Entire Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968643/eclipse-ignore-entire-directories/972450#972450)

Answer (score 1):

To exclude entire projects, you could close them. Don't know a way for individual directories.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but I don't know anything about such a setting. As one already mentioned you could close the project within Eclipse (once it is open). This prevents the repetitive refreshing on that project. Otherwise I can just give you the suggestion to have 1 workspace per project and not include multiple different projects into the same workspace (unless they are related to each other). This is a much better practice and what I'm doing every day when working with Eclipse. And I didn't experience any problems so far of the type you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this same problem. When an eclipse project refreshes it seems to want to touch every file regardless of settings. The code base I'm working on has ~70K files, and took nearly 2 minutes to refresh. I eventually redefined the eclipse project to be a much smaller subset of that (~10K files) that has a ~ 1 second refresh. Not ideal, but the long refresh times are intolerable.

FYI the "Derived" check box and "Exclude from build..." options DON'T prevent a folder from being refreshed.

Note, the computer I'm using is 4-5 years old (Pentium IV processor, 7200 rpm hard drive). I bet one of these newer fast solid state hard drives would dramatically improve refresh times!

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to stop auto refreshing at eclipse startup.Below are the steps:-

Windows->Preferences->(Search Keyword:-Workspace)->General->Startup And ShutDown->Uncheck Referesh workspace on start up.

Done ...!!!
Work like charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file .project inside the folder .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders of your workspace folder.

Then remove any content between the linkedResources tags.

That worked for me (eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32)

Answer (score 0):

You know what. Just close unused projects and that's was all for me.!