# Eclipse stop background refresh

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse 3.7

This is not related to [How do I stop Eclipse from refreshing some dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993545/how-do-i-stop-eclipse-from-refreshing-some-dir) as I am okay with eclipse project refresh on startup.

I have my project sources in a network drive (I need to use Eclipse in Windows and Run the code in Linux). Periodically Eclipse freezes and I am fairly sure this is because Windows is frantically trying to access the NAS area and it is slow. I would not be changing the source files outside of Eclipse so I don't need features in eclipse such as refreshing a file when it is changed in background.

Questions

- Are there any known ways of speeding this up? Suggestions like disabling local history, refreshes etc?
- I also have a feeling that this freezing is because Eclipse tries to actively detect if files are changed in a file system and when you do that over several files it causes delays (I can be wrong on this). Is there any way to disable this? (In IntelliJ I could do a background refresh)

Comment: Isn't there a preference under Workspace for enabling/disabling automatic refresh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `Preferences / General / Workspace` and see if `Refresh using native hooks or polling` and `Refresh on access` are checked. If so try turning them off.

Comment: Thanks !! It really helps.

Comment: I've always had these options turned off, and it still does it.