# Eclipse "Refresh Status" error

Tags: eclipse

1. When I import a project into eclipse or reopen a closed project I get a "Refresh status"  error, see below:

[image: Import/Reopen Error]

2. When I delete a project from workspace, I get similar error then as well, see below:

[image: Delete Error]

What is the cause of this error, and how can I get rid of this error?

Any help would be appreciated !

==> 
By looking at error messages related to "Refresh status..." it seems 
that problem is with Mercurial plugin. See below section of log file:

---

***!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-09-07 13:06:17.090
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Refresh status...".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
    at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.team.cache.MercurialStatusCache.clearStatusCache(MercurialStatusCache.java:1377)
    at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.team.cache.MercurialStatusCache.clear(MercurialStatusCache.java:1459)
    at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.team.cache.MercurialStatusCache.refreshStatus(MercurialStatusCache.java:855)
    at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.team.cache.MercurialStatusCache$ProjectUpdateJob.updateProject(MercurialStatusCache.java:143)
    at com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.team.cache.MercurialStatusCache$ProjectUpdateJob.run(MercurialStatusCache.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)***

---

Added details of installed softwares. See below for installed softwares:

[image]

Comment: See answer here, it may be useful in optimizing eclipse's working. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993545/how-do-i-stop-eclipse-from-refreshing-some-dir

Comment: Could you please add the error log to your answer. Which Eclipse version do you use and which plug-ins do you have installed?

Comment: Added error from log file and details of installed softwares/plugins.

Comment: Hi howlger, With the error log and details of installed softwares, Can you please guide me that how can I solve this issue?